# Integration of $\int x^{4} (x^2+x+1)^{1/2}dx $

Tags: calculus

I have tried integration by parts but couldn't work it out because of multiple $x$ variables in the square root. $$\int x^{4} (x^2+x+1)^{1/2}dx $$

Comment: Maybe: Complete the square under the radical.  Trigonometric substitution.

Comment: [Solution is horrible](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E4(x%5E2%2Bx%2B1)%5E0.5)...

Comment: Same way, integrate x^19(x^2+x+1)^0.5.. you cant beat a machine. We need to show how the polynomial builds up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write the integral in the form $$\int x^4\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}dx$$ and substitute $$u=x+\frac{1}{2}$$ and then we get $du=dx$
and the we get
$$\int\left(u-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4\sqrt{u^2+\frac{3}{4}}du$$ and substitute now
$$u=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tan(s)$$ with $$du=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sec^2(s)ds$$

Comment: It should be $du=dx$

Comment: yes that is right

Comment: What with the 4th power equation ... It is to be expanded , right ?

Comment: So we got rid of the square root but we have 3 trig functions in the equation. How will we be able to get that 4th power down ? Everything until here made sense, I can see there is the derivative of tan(s) and itself there but I can't seem to move on after this step

Comment: @Sam You have to compute functions of the form $\tan^k s \sec^n s$, which is trivial if $k=1$. I'll end this comment with a link that shows you what to do when $k=0$. Finally, $\tan^2 s = \sec^2 s -1$ lets you deal with high-$k$ cases. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Comment: I got the idea now, thank you all for your time

Comment: Correction: by compute I meant integrate.

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-The result is not as concise as I would like to have. Put $\dfrac{\sqrt3u-1}{2}=x$ so you get
$$\int x^{4} (x^2+x+1)^{1/2}dx=\int\left(\dfrac{\sqrt3u-1}{2}\right)^4\sqrt{u^2+1}\space du$$
You must solve
$$\int(A_1u^4+A_2u^3+A_3u^2+A_4u+A_5)\sqrt{u^2+1}\space du$$ and it is easy to solve each integral summand.